# Why this error occurred my server is not started and site is down?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, apache2, passenger

In my rails application, I am using

```
Apache + ruby 1.9.2p180 + Rails 3.0.5 + Phusion Passenger version 3.0.13
```

Here is my error

> This application process is currently running as user 'nobody' and group 'nobody' and must be able to access its application root directory '/home/mystore /mystore '. However the parent directory '/home/mystore ' has wrong permissions, thereby preventing this process from accessing its application root directory. Please fix the permissions of the directory '/home/mystore ' first.

and when i look into my app it's empty but my database got the sample from spree. whats seems to be the problem?

Please somebody help me

I am using 
ruby 1.9.2p180 
Rails 3.0.5 
Phusion Passenger version 3.0.13

Comment: What version of rails are you using? Are you using mod_rails, unicorn, etc.? VPS or shared hosting? Add whatever you think we might find useful.

Comment: Hey I am really in hurry because i don't know what to do suddenly my site is going down. Please help me.

Comment: It looks to me like you may have a space in some config file for `/home/mystore`, as in the error message it's coming as `home/mystore[SPACE]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution on it.
It occured due to

```
PassengerUserSwitching on
```

In passenger config file.

I turn it to `off` and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing this issue in Rails 5 + Apache2, then add the following 2 [Passenger Security Option](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/apache/reference/#passengerdefaultuser) into your Apache config file:

```
PassengerDefaultUser username
PassengerDefaultGroup username
```

and then restart the Apache server.